# Варнинг неконтролируемого input в React+Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

Всем привет, у меня в комоненте, содержащем форму с инпутами выскакивает варнинг

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
const EditPageModal = (props) => {

  const { 
    categories, 
    pageDetails, 
    handlerInputsValue,
    updateEditPage } = props;

  const validateForm = (obj) => {
    // ......
  } 

 let categoriesList = ERROR_TEXT;
  
 if(categories.length !== 0){
    categoriesList = categories.map((item, index)=>{

       return(
          <option
            key={index}
            className={item.catClass}
            value={item._id}>{item.catName}</option>
       )
    });
 }

 return(
  <div className="modal fade" id="modal-editpage" tabIndex="-1" role="dialog" 
         aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
      <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div className="modal-content">
          <div className="modal-header alert-success">
            <h5 
             className="modal-title" 
             id="exampleModalLongTitle">
             Editor Page
           </h5>
            <button 
             type="button" className="close" 
             data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div className="modal-body">

            <form className="form-signin" onSubmit={(e)=>e.preventDefault()}>

<div className="form-label-group">
 <input onChange={(ev) => handlerInputsValue(ev.target.value, ev.target.id)}
     value={pageDetails.name}
 type="text" id="name" className="form-control" 
  placeholder="enter Name Page"
         aria-describedby="editPage" />
  <label htmlFor="name">Name Page</label>
 </div>

        <div className="form-label-group">
          <input
                  value={pageDetails.link} 
                  onChange={(ev) => handlerInputsValue(ev.target.value, ev.target.id)}
           type="text" id="link" className="form-control" 
           placeholder="enter Link Page"
                  aria-describedby="editPage" />
          <label htmlFor="link">Link Page</label>
        </div>

        <div className="form-label-group">
          <input
                  value={pageDetails.screen} 
                  onChange={(ev) => handlerInputsValue(ev.target.value, ev.target.id)}
           type="text" id="screen" className="form-control" 
           placeholder="enter Link Preview Page"
                  aria-describedby="editPage" />
          <label htmlFor="screen">Link Preview Page</label>
        </div>

        <div className="form-label-group">
         <select
                  value={pageDetails.ctgrId}
                  onChange={(ev) => handlerInputsValue(ev.target.value, ev.target.id)}
            id="ctgrId" className="form-control"
                  aria-describedby="editPage" >
              {categoriesList}
           </select>
          <label htmlFor="type">Select Cathegorie</label>
        </div>

              <div className="form-label-group">
                <input
                  value={pageDetails.orderNum}
                  onChange={(ev) => handlerInputsValue(ev.target.value, ev.target.id)}
                  type="number" id="orderNum" 
                  className="form-control" 
                  placeholder="order page"
                  aria-describedby="editPage" />
                <label htmlFor="orderNum">Order Page</label>
              </div>

        <button 
                id="editPage"
                className="btn btn-info btn-block" type="button"
                onClick={(ev)=>validateForm(
                  {
                    _id: pageDetails._id,
                    name: pageDetails.name, 
                    link: pageDetails.link, 
                    ctgrId: pageDetails.ctgrId,
                    ctgrClass: pageDetails.ctgrClass,
                    ctgrColor: pageDetails.ctgrColor,
                    ctgrBGC: pageDetails.ctgrBGC,
                    userId: pageDetails.userId,
                    screen: pageDetails.screen,
                    orderNum: Number(pageDetails.orderNum)
                  }
                )}>
                Save Page Changes
              </button>
      </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

В документации указано, что value должно использоваться c onChange(). Не пойму в чём ошибка

Answer (score 0):

В значении, которое вы присваиваете компоненту. Вы неправильно его определяете и кидаете в input.
Сколько уже можно. 
https://itnext.io/controlled-and-uncontrolled-component-design-pattern-in-react-21e8d40e46e

Comment: Да, спасибо, разобрался, ответ нашёлся тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50715760/react-mobx-warning-a-component-is-changing-an-uncontrolled-input

Comment: В моём случае можно сделать так в отношении value={nameProps == null ? '' : nameProps}

Answer (score 0):

Инпуты в React являются контролируемыми или неконтролируемыми в зависимости от наличия значения пропсы `value` на входе. То есть, передав пропсу `value` еще не будет означать, что компонент будет контролируемым. Дело в том, что передав начальное значение `undefined` - React всегда запускает `input` в неконтролируемом режиме (он считает, что значения нет).

После того, как Вы начнете изменять значение `input`, и значение изменится с `undefined` на какое-то конкретное значение в строковом эквиваленте - тогда React переключит `input` в контролируемый режим, и Вы получаете предупреждение в консоли браузера.

Для решения такой простой проблемы - есть простой ответ. Необходимо инициализировать значение `input` элемента - пустой строкой по-умолчанию. Пример с проверкой через тернарку:

```
value={pageDetails && !!pageDetails.orderNum ? pageDetails.orderNum : ''}
```

Ссылка на ответ SO: [React-Mobx Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50722189/5275890)

Answer (score 0):

Добавь атрибут defaultValue на input

```
<input type=“text” onchage=“func” value=“value” defaultValue=“value” />
```